# How to convert an Array to Array of objects with same keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Consider a simple array that contains a set of values.

```
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'];
```

I'd like to convert the above array into,

```
[
  { name: 'ab' },
  { name: 'cd' },
  { name: 'ef' }
];
```

What I've tried:

```
arr.reduce((a, c) => ((a[c] = c), a), {});
```

Comment: `arr.map(name => ({ name }))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `Array.map`, which allows you to specify a function that returns a new item to replace in the array.

```js
arr.map(o => ({ name: o }))
```

Here's one without fancy arrow function shorthand, just in case you are confused.

```js
arr.map(function(o) {
   return {
      name: o,
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach() and create a new array of objects pushing each new object.

```
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'];

const newObjArr = [];

arr.forEach((str) => newObjArr.push({ name: str }))

console.log(newObjArr); //[ { name: 'ab' }, { name: 'cd' }, { name: 'ef' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> You've tried:     `arr.reduce((a, c) => ((a[c] = c), a), {});`

Your code there are 2 problems:

1. `{}`: The initialValue should be the `Array` instead.
2. `(a[c] = c`: You want to define the specific `name` instead of each `c` value

[**The `.reduce` syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#syntax)

> arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[,
> initialValue])

The finish solution `.reduce` should be like this:

```js
const arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, currItem) => {
  acc.push({name: currItem});
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Or just `.map()` like this.

```js
const arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'];

const result = arr.map(item => ({name: item}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`With Object.fromEntries, you can convert from Array to Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'];

const result = arr.map(item => Object.fromEntries([["name",item]]));

console.log(result);
```